# Heroku. Django. South. Database column does not exist

Tags: database, django, heroku, django-south

I am new to Heroku. I just migrated my django models using south:

```
sudo heroku run python manage.py migrate
```

I get the message "Nothing to migrate" in all of my six apps.

Then when I try to visit the website I get the error:

ProgrammingError "column X does not exist".

Everything works fine locally. What should I do, drop the database and recreate it again? If that is the answer, how do I do that on Heroku?

Thanks for you help.

Comment: Are you sure you added your migrations to the git repository before pushing to heroku?

Comment: No. I am not sure if I did that. ... I didn't include them in .gitignore though. What do you think should I do now?

Comment: You can do a `git status` to see if there are any files not in the repository.

Comment: So yes, everything appears to be up to date. I have to say I had some problems before this one with the database. I faked some migrations, django debug toolbar also gave me trouble. So, if I want to drop the database & restart migrations, how do I achieve that? I am a noob in Heroku.

Answer (score 1):

To drop the database on heroku, run:

```
heroku pg:psql
```

as per https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#pg-psql.

Then do:

```
drop database <database name>;
create database <database name>;
```

Then you can try and run your migrations again.

Comment: Thanks, that helped restart everything. However, I can't get Heroku&South&Django working. Same error always showing up. Dont know why.

Comment: The error changed to "relation X does not exist". I tried couple of more times: reset database, syncdb, fake migrations, migrate. Then I got tired and removed South from my installed apps and now it works. I think the Internet is missing a good South&Heroku tutorial, too many weird errors. Thank you Nicholas for your time and help.

Comment: No problem, I hope you get your app up and running!